Bound on Joint Discrete and Differentialy Entropy
I am looking at bounding the entropy of a graph ensemble, and have run into the following issue: Let $X = (X_{12},...,X_{(n-1)n})$ be a vector of $\{0,1\}$ dependent random variables, and $R = (R_1,...,R_n)$ be a vector of dependent $\mathcal{K}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$-valued continuous random variables with distribution $f_R(r)$ (which is uniform) where $\mathcal{K}$ is a compact set with volume $V$. We have
$$
H(X|R) \leq H(X) \leq H(X,R)
$$
The upper bound is
$$
H(X,R) = H(X|R) + H(R)
$$
Also,
$$
H(R) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n
H(R_i)$$
and $$H(R_i) = -\int_{\mathcal{K}}f_R(r)\log f_R(r)dr = -\int_{\mathcal{K}}\frac{1}{V}\log\frac{1}{V}dr = \log V$$
I don't think I have made a mistake here (or if I have I can't see it!), but my question is that this implies
$$
H(X|R) \leq H(X) \leq H(X|R) + n\log V$$
but what happens when $V\leq 1$? This will break the order of the bounds? I assume this issue comes from using differntial entropy interchangeably with discrete entropy, but I'm not sure how to fix it?

You must be careful when working with continuous random variables, because differential entropy does not behave like Shannon entropy for discrete laws. In particular, things like $H(X,R)$ need to be considered carefully.
As a rule of thumb, you're basically fine if you're always working with mutual information, which is robust to the continuous-discrete issue. This still lets you work with differential entropies, if you like, but every such entropy would have a corresponding conditioned entropy to go with it. Working with this view, $$I(X;R) = h(R) - h(R|X) = H(X) - H(X|R),$$ and this tells us that $$ H(X) = H(X|R) + h(R) - h(R|X).$$ Of course $H(X|R) \le H(X)$ holds, but the claim that $H(X) \le H(X|R) + h(R)$ does not follow unless $h(R|X) > 0$. Note that if $h(R) < 0,$ then $I(R;X) > 0 \implies h(R|X) \le h(R) < 0,$ and the issue you're encountering does not occur. In any case, for your specific situation, you must verify that $h(R|X) \ge 0$ if you want to use a bound like the one you have, and of course this would in turn imply that $V \ge 1$.
